# servlet Server-sent event not working with Chrome/Safari

Tags: html, jsp, servlets, server-sent-events

I am working on servlet but encountered a problem. The SSE works fine with Firefox but cannot work with Chrome/Safari. The similar code in PHP can run smoothly in all three browsers mentioned above. How to solve the problem? Thx!!

This is my servlet code:

```
    response.setContentType("text/event-stream;charset=UTF-8");
    response.addHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    out.print("data: " + new Date());
    out.flush();
    out.close();
```

And this is my JS code:

```
           if (typeof(EventSource) !== "undefined")
        {
            var source = new EventSource("sse");
            source.onmessage = function(event)
            {
                document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += event.data + "<br />";
                alert("ok");
            };
        }
        else
        {
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Sorry, your browser does not support server-sent events...";
        }
```

BTW, i am using Glassfish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may want to modify the line
out.print("data: " + new Date());
like that
out.print("data: " + new Date() + " \n\n");
the browser normally gets stuck finding no double "\n" at the end of SSE data message.